# How can I pass in parameters into a rails edit link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I have a model

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

and in a form, I want to link to a specific instance using

```
edit_a_path
```

but I also want to submit a parameter, similar to

```
<%= link_to "New A",
    new_a_path(:b=> {:id => @b.id})%>
```

How can I do this? I tried

```
edit_a_path(:b=> {:id => @b.id}, @a)
```

but I get an error. Also, **bonus points** if you reference the API documentation. I could not find an API reference for these methods.

---

In my original code, I had a typo, but the correct way to do this is

```
edit_a_path(@a, :b=> {:id => @b.id})
```

Comment: The parameter is a hash? I don't think you can pass a hash like that.

Comment: The parameter is indeed a hash

Comment: @Gerry Do you know where I can find the magic behind these tools in the API docs?

Comment: What error are you getting? I just tried passing a hash into one of my paths and it worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. I always refer to the guides, but this specific topic is not mentioned.

Comment: @jvillian Sorry, I had a typo. It turns out the second choice does not work though

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me:

`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_object_path(object, foo: {bar: true}) %>`

```
Started GET "/objects/1/edit?foo%5Bbar%5D=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-03 07:45:59 +0000
Processing by ObjectsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"true"}, "id"=>"1"}
```